# PHP page returns junk instead of return string in objective-C

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I'm building an `iOS` app using `Xcode`. In that, I need to get a value from an online `php page`: [index.php](http://www.mediafire.com/edit/l8lba665t24h3dg/index.php).

I don't know how to do that. I've tried the following:

```
    NSString *urlstr = [[NSString alloc] 
          initWithFormat:@"http://www.mediafire.com/edit/l8lba665t24h3dg/index.php"];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlstr];
    NSString *ans = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url 
                                             encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding 
                                                error:nil];
    NSLog(@"ans--------->%@",ans); // This returns the whole page :(
    [urlstr release];
    [url release];
```

Is it is the right way to do this? Then how to get the return string? I need the return string only as: `"Hello, PHP!"` (ie., the php output). Please, please help me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it's the right way, you have the same result on your NSLog as rigth click on your page and show source code.
Your url index.php is in plain text and not interpreted by the server, is why you haven't "Hello, PHP!" as a result.

see php hello world tutorial : http://www.utexas.edu/learn/php/example1.shtml

the result: http://www.utexas.edu/learn/php/ex1.php

change your code :

```
NSString *urlstr = [[NSString alloc] 
      initWithFormat:@"http://www.utexas.edu/learn/php/ex1.php"];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlstr];
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. But it still returns the whole html page string. I need the return string to be: 'Hello World' only. For that, wht I have to do? Pls help.

Comment: ok, bad example ... because use of html tags, text what's you see is translated by the browser, but stringWithContentsOfURL return the entire page with html tags ( equivalent to rigth click on the page > source code )

  1.Copy index.php to your web hosting server 
  2.Call your url

Answer (score 2):

That isn't a PHP page; it's an online editor containing a snippet of PHP code. You need to actually save it to a file that's served from a PHP-savvy webserver (e.g. Apache) in order to get the result of executing the script.

Comment: can u suggest me the method to store my file or any other alternatives(where or how can I save it) pls?